# QT4: Transparent Window with rounded corners

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, qt4

#### How can I create a partially transparent window with rounded borders (no standard borders)?

(I used `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` to disable standard borders)

I tried stylesheets, but `border-radius` and `opacity` doesn't seem to have any effect on the window, it only works on children of the enclosing widget.

My second idea was to make the window fully transparent (with `setWindowOpacity`), and then add an additional widget with rounded corners (since `border-radius` works on the children), and then group all my other widgets into that widget. But that does not work since `setWindowOpacity` affects all children as well (I haven't found a way to change this behaviour).

And any ways to make the outer window transparent I could think of (like stylesheets `opacity`) don't work properly (I only get a black box instead of a transparent window)

**Any help would be highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to paint on a toplevel widget and have only the painted part appear.  setWindowOpacity changed the opacity of the painted part, which I didn't want.

```
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
```

changed the opacity of the widget without the painted part.  I just tried tossing on a button, and that also displays perfectly opaque.  So you *should* be able to display other children however you like.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should use a widget masks, as seen in the following example from Qt :

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-shapedclock-example.html

I think you'll find what you're looking for in it !

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Yeah, that could be a solution, however it isnt that easy to create a rectangular mask with rounded borders.

Well i could use QPixmaps to get such an QRegion, but would the application still be scalable afterwards ?

Comment: got it working quite well:
[code]
   QPixmap qpm(":/alphamask.png");
   qpm = qpm.scaled(this->width(),this->height(),Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation);
   if (!qpm.isNull())
      this->setMask(qpm.mask());
   this->setWindowOpacity(0.9);
[/code]

Comment: Hello
i tried to search the web for examples on how should the alpha mask image  
should look like , but i didn't found any examples.  
say i have the Gimp image editor .what should be in the alpha image map  
so it could work with the QPixmap ?  
( i have no idea on images and graphics )

Answer (score 2):

```
 void MainForm::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * /* event */)
{
    QImage image(this->size(), QImage::Format_Mono);
    image.fill(0);

    if(!this->isFullScreen() && !this->isMaximized())
    {
        image.setPixel(0, 0, 1); image.setPixel(1, 0, 1); image.setPixel(2, 0, 1); image.setPixel(3, 0, 1);
        image.setPixel(0, 1, 1); image.setPixel(1, 1, 1);
        image.setPixel(0, 2, 1);
        image.setPixel(0, 3, 1);

        image.setPixel(width() - 4, 0, 1); image.setPixel(width() - 3, 0, 1); image.setPixel(width() - 2, 0, 1); image.setPixel(width() - 1, 0, 1);
                                                                              image.setPixel(width() - 2, 1, 1); image.setPixel(width() - 1, 1, 1);
                                                                                                                 image.setPixel(width() - 1, 2, 1);
                                                                                                                 image.setPixel(width() - 1, 3, 1);

        image.setPixel(0, height() - 4, 1);
        image.setPixel(0, height() - 3, 1);
        image.setPixel(0, height() - 2, 1); image.setPixel(1, height() - 2, 1);
        image.setPixel(0, height() - 1, 1); image.setPixel(1, height() - 1, 1); image.setPixel(2, height() - 1, 1); image.setPixel(3, height() - 1, 1);

                                                                                                                                                  image.setPixel(width() - 1, height() - 4, 1);
                                                                                                                                                  image.setPixel(width() - 1, height() - 3, 1);
                                                                                                    image.setPixel(width() - 2, height() - 2, 1); image.setPixel(width() - 1, height() - 2, 1);
        image.setPixel(width() - 4, height() - 1, 1); image.setPixel(width() - 3, height() - 1, 1); image.setPixel(width() - 2, height() - 1, 1); image.setPixel(width() - 1, height() - 1, 1);
    }
    this->setMask(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}
```

Comment: why did you put this in resizeEvent?