# Non-standard windows with Qt

Tags: windows, qt, user-interface

Is it possible to create a non-standard window with Qt? I mean that I want to create an application with rounded-corner windows and buttons with aqua-like effects. The principal thing is that the app must be beautiful, not compliant with any Windows or Mac GUI reference... 
Can Qt do these things, or it is preferable to use another toolkit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use stylesheets to create a custom look for your buttons. Refer to the Qt documentation for some [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-a-qpushbutton-using-the-box-model).

To create non-rectangular windows, use `QWidget::setMask`. Again, the documentation features an [example application](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-shapedclock-example.html) demonstrating this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Non-rectangular windows are probably the hardest, but are possible: http://qt.nokia.com/developer/faqs/356

Buttons are trivial. QButton is a QWidget with OS-default effects. But if you create a FancyButton derived from QWidget, you decide how it looks. Aqua effects, mouse over effects, it's all a matter of drawing what you want to draw.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look here! You'll find what you're looking for...

[QT4: Transparent Window with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909092/qt4-transparent-window-with-rounded-corners)