# How can I make a transparent window stay on top?

Tags: qt, background, opacity, transparent, qt4.6

I'm trying to make a transparent window stays on top (z-order).

I want to implement something like layer that indicates some parameters on the other program.

So what I need is to make background transparent, not whole widget with QWidget::setWindowOpacity function.

I found some documents about it

1. [Transparent Backgrounds in Qt 4.1](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq16-background.html)
2. [QWidget Class Reference — Transparency and Double Buffering](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qwidget.html#transparency-and-double-buffering)

**The first one** explains "New in Qt 4.1: The Backing Store" and the picture is exactly what I want.

**The second one** explains more details about it. (left picture)

> The left widget has no additional properties or widget attributes set. This default state suits most custom widgets using transparency, are irregularly-shaped, or do not paint over their entire area with an opaque brush.

But I don't know how to do it. I'm using Qt 4.6 B.T.W.

Comment: I think my answer here is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909092/qt4-transparent-window-with-rounded-corners/1910052#1910052

Answer (score 0):

Taken from ctd's answer as suggested in the comments: [QT4: Transparent Window with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909092/qt4-transparent-window-with-rounded-corners/1910052#1910052)

```
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
```