# C++ Autopatcher GUI (With a unique skin)

Tags: c++, user-interface

Can you please take a look at this picture of a game launcher:

[image http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5sHFYgzDSqE/TiRrdl2cUmI/AAAAAAAAAJs/ULE76E6Nwwo/s400/Launcher.png](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5sHFYgzDSqE/TiRrdl2cUmI/AAAAAAAAAJs/ULE76E6Nwwo/s400/Launcher.png)

How can I create something identical? (using my own art)
Everything about the design I just love, I downloaded qt, wxWidgets, nuilib and several others, but they either do not compile well or bloated and damn difficult to use.

Does anyone know the exact widget library that most asian mmorpgs use? Like that picture.

Answer (score 3):

Those are just drawn images. It is trivial with any toolkit.

Qt, GTK and wxWidgets are the most prominent toolkits. I would recommend Qt, since it is very widely supported. But you can do this even with plain WinAPI or XLib.

Comment: QT can do image window like that? you sure? I mean I dont want to have the regular windows style window borders and an image inside, I want the image to be the main window

Comment: @RogerG Just search for transparent window.

Comment: @RogerG There are even questions on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909092/qt4-transparent-window-with-rounded-corners